# Dynamically select options in Select while loading via jQuery

Tags: jquery, joomla, jquery-chosen

I am dynamically loading a multi select box with options as below.  The code works great however I am not able to set the selected options as default.

```
items = JSON.parse(result);

jQuery.each(items, function (i, item) {
  selected = item['selected']?'selected':'';
  jQuery('#student_ids').append(jQuery('<option>', { 
    value: item['id'],
    text : item['value'] 
  }));
});

jQuery('#student_ids').trigger("liszt:updated");
```

How can i use the `selected` variable inside the append function to mark an item is selected?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work with the below code.

```
items = JSON.parse(result);

jQuery.each(items, function (i, item) {
  selected = item['selected']?'selected':false;
  jQuery('#student_ids')
    .append(jQuery("<option></option>")
    .attr("value",item['id'])
    .attr("selected", selected)
    .text(item['value'])); 
});

jQuery('#student_ids').trigger("liszt:updated");
```